# Is there a way to use the spotify WEB API to check if spotify is installed?

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

Basically what I am trying to to is create a list of links of which will link to Spotify using a Spotify URI if Spotify is installed and just plain text if it is not installed.

from my knowledge this:

> spotify:track:7yOKhepYf8pO8ILT2Z5KN1

If input into the browser and Spotify is installed it will immediately launch the track or what ever you request.

If Spotify is not installed this just runs a normal browser request.

I have looked in documentation for something I can hook into but I just cant find anything that is usable on an external application, Just to reiterate this application is not a native Spotify application.

What I am looking for as an end result is a method to call that checks if Spotify is installed to return true, if it is not installed return false.

The requirement is using HTML CSS and JavaScript Only.

Comment: I doubt this is possible. It seems like Spotify links work by the Spotify app registering itself as a URL handler, and you can't detect the available URL handles. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836777/how-to-detect-browsers-protocol-handlers). That is, unless Spotify installs a browser plugin.

Comment: It would be a security risk if it was possible, so I doubt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you write a browser plugin with something like [firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org), I do not believe that this is possible for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I've not looked too in depth into this yet but you can contact a local Spotify client using the spotilocal.com domain (just a DNS reference to 127.0.0.1) on port 4380.

If it allows CORS then you should be able to call this URL using javascript:

http://1234.spotilocal.com:4380/remote/status.json

And see what the result is.

This is how Facebook does its Spotify integration as can be seen here:

[What is the advantage of having a domain name (spotilocal) that resolves to 127.0.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580175/what-is-the-advantage-of-having-a-domain-name-spotilocal-that-resolves-to-127)

UPDATE

If you are in Chrome, open your dev tools on this page and paste and run this in the console:

```
$.get('http://1234.spotilocal.com:4380/remote/status.json', function(data){console.log(data)});
```

<strike>The response header contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` so you should be able to call that URL using AJAX from your page</strike>

UPDATE 2 (24/07/13)

The newest version of the spotify client (I'm on 0.9.1.57) no longer includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and the method above therefore no longer works.